# Physijs jittering mesh and wrong rotation?

Tags: three.js, physijs

I am making a game in three.js and I have 2 questions. 1. I have a cube which gets pushed along but every few seconds it "Jitters" back a little. Why?. 2. When i click the left or right arrow key the cube meant to rotate on its Y-axis instead of rotating one way it sometimes rotates a little one way and then the other?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I realised that I was updating the camera in the **Renderer update function** not the **physics update function** so I moved it and now there is no jittering. Also for the rotation I changed .rotation.y -= 0.1; to .rotateOnAxis( new THREE.Vector3(0,1,0), -0.05); and now it works.